# Access Query subtract 2 different column from different row in same table with same ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

I have a table `deposit` which have column `Refund_amt` ,`Deposit_amt` having different Rows with same `GR_no` . here my question is ,I want to subtract `deposit_amt` column from `Refund_amt` 
I tried various alternative in query but didn't succeed

**My query :**

```
SELECT d.Gr_no
     , d.Rec_No
     , d.Deposite_Amt
     , d.penalty_Amt
     , d.Refund_Amt - Refund 
     , s.Name
     , s.cur_std
     , cur_div 
  From  
     ( select d.Refund_Amt refund 
         from deposite d 
            , std_gr s  
        where d.Gr_no = s.Gr_no   )
```

**Result would look like this in `final total` column :**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: can you pls give desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an aggregation per std_gr: the sum of the deposites minus the sum of the refunds. One way is to do this aggregation in a subquery and join this subquery to your table.

```
select 
  d.*, sums.final_total
from deposite d
join
(
  select std_gr, nz(sum(deposite_amt),0) - nz(sum(refund_amt),0) as final_total
  from deposite
  group by std_gr
) as sums on sums.std_gr = d.std_gr
order by d.rec_no;
```

Comment: Thank you .yeah I exactly want by this only